# Excel Sequence number based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

In excel, how can I create auto numbering in column A ? eg. If I key in cell value in D1 with "BILLY", column A will populate sequence numbers from 1,2,3.....

I have googled and found the closet is using below formula but unable to accomplish what i want because in column C i have multiple data need to select.

https://superuser.com/questions/645859/auto-sequential-numbering-based-on-cell-criteria/645903

```
A     B     C
     ABC    JAMES
     XYZ    BOB
1    OXY    BILLY
2    BNX    BILLY
     SDA    MIKE
3    WXK    BILLY
     SAK    JANE
```

Anyone have done this before with formula or vba? would appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: I think you just need to shorten the formula supplied in the answers already - in A1 use `=COUNTIF(C1:$C$1,C1)`.  I assume your note that _in column C i have multiple data need to select_ means you want a running count of each item in column C?

Comment: I want to set selection based on criteria In column C, eg. Billy. Is there anyway i can select all? any wildcard i can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the whole column A or just the cells that you want to fill in and enter the formula in the formula bar,

```
=IF(C1=D$1,COUNTIF(C$1:C1,D$1),"")
```

Press `ctrl+enter` to fill the formula for the range of selected cells.

You could then change the value in cell `D1` and see the output.

[image]

[image]

Comment: you are awesome! very clear explanation, thank your for your great help!

Comment: hi any formula or wildcard i can use if i want to select all persons? column A will show from 1,2,3,4,5.....if D1 i put "*" ? I have tried it's not working

Comment: Nope, Thats not possible !!

Comment: You'd need to use `COUNTA` to count everything - it counts the number of cells that aren't empty in a range.  You just need an `IF` statement to decide whether to use `COUNTA` or `COUNTIF`:  `=IF($D$1="*",COUNTA(C$1:C1),IF(C1=D$1,COUNTIF(C$1:C1,D$1),""))`

Comment: Can I insert unique number ? In above example, I want to fill A1 for Billy 1 time, not 3 time.  Can it be done ?

Comment: Darren Bartrup-Cook, your code work perfectly! thank you for your sharing, many learning today, hope i can do the same in the future for others !!

Answer (score 2):

Put the formula `=IF(C1=$D$1,COUNTIF($C$1:C1,$D$1),"")` in A1 and copied down.